# Using ASP.NET 5, hide index.html in url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've followed some basic tutorials to create ASP.NET 5 with MVC 6 and AngularJS applications.

I've got a setup like so:

```
index.html
app.js
```

When I load the project, I have to go to index.html, or set it as the Launch URL to naturally visit my webpage.  this means that the url browser shows:

```
http://localhost:16510/index.html
```

How can I set up the ASP.NET 5.0 project so that when the user goes to / it views index.html?

e.g.

```
http:localhost:16510/
```

Comment: Your situation may be different...however I always right click the project in the solution explorer select properties  then click web then under "Start Action" select the option "Specific Page" and the leave the textbox blank your project should start up on the default "home" page. Assuming that your using Visual Studio...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put the code of `index.htm`l in the `/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`.

In the startup.cs you have your default route configuration.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

This tells that your default controller is `Home` and default action method is `Index`. So whenever you accesss your site without a controllername & action name in your url, the request will be send to `Home/Index`. Your url will be `http://yourSiteName`